# Does refactoring Entity from one-to-many relationship to one-to-one ralationship which has its own one-to-may for easy updates have any sense?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

Good day everyone.

I'm kinda facing some strange dilemma and can't figure out if it make any sense.

Lets say I have:

```
public class Training {
    .........
    @OneToMany
    List progress = new AutoPopulatingList();

    @OneToMany
    List workout = new AutoPopulatingList();
    ........
}
```

Now if I only need progress data, which will be manipulated, some **progress** objects to this list added, some other removed.
(I will get **training** object from DB with eagerly populated **progress** list and **workout** list will be empty as it's lazy loaded).

So in the jsp form:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="training" action="/updateTraining" id="trainingData"> 
...........
</form:form>
```

So now if I want to save changes, my **workout** data is not present and it simply gets deleted. But eagerly loading all data seems silly, so what about this way:

```
public class Training {
    .........
    @OneToOne
    ProgressJoin progress;

    @OneToMany
    List workout = new AutoPopulatingList();
    ........
}

public class ProgressJoin {
    ..........
    @OneToOne
    Training training 

    @OneToMany
    List progress = new AutoPopulatingList();   
    ..........
}
```

Now I just simply get **PgoressJoin** object from separate table, make changes to **progress** list and save it.

So my question, is it ok ? Does anybody do like this ? Maybe there is a smarter way ?

Comment: You said: *So now if I want to save changes, my workout data is not present and it simply gets deleted.*. That's where your problem is. It seems you're recreating an instance of Training from scratch. You shouldn't. Get the existing Training, and update it with the data you got from the form, leaving the workout list untouched.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for response. But I still don't get it. If I get Training object from DB and from repository it's passed to controller, from controller it's passed to view (jsp) and then back from view it's passed to controller but with additional progress data. But then when I want to save it, it lacks workout data and hibernate/jpa thinks as it was deleted and deletes it from DB.... but this workout data wasn't even loaded because its crazy to load data which is not needed (lazy loading).

Comment: The workflow of the form submission should instead be: 1. get ID of updated entity from submitted form data; 2. get entity from database using this ID; 3. update entity with submitted form data.

Comment: I see. So as I understand, since data are submitted and ready to be saved, I should get training object in persistence method, set new data and the whole stuff which was not initialized (left as lazy) should not bother me :) Thank you very much.